# Using class functions and handling data externally - PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Just a small question. I have a class that does something and handles strings. I have an active class that has a button which when pressed closes the screen and deactivates the class at the same time. I would like the class to return the strings it has been handling to variables that are outside the class itself., but I am not sure how to do this.

```
    class InputBox:
       def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
           #... Instructions for defining the class.
       def Otherinstructions():
           #... Other instructions
       def returnVar(): # The function to return text externally.
           return InputBox.text

     NewVar = '' # I would like the class to return the string to this variable.
```

Thank you. I just want to find out the most effective way.

Answer (score 0):

```py
box = InputBox(<your data>)
NewVar = box.returnVar()
```

Although you should follow the style convention where methods and variables begin with a lowercase character. For future reference, the `returnVar()` method is called a *getter*.

Comment: It should be something like `new_var`, `return_var()` and `other_instructions()`, according to PEP8. See: [Function Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45)